# OS Concepts Terminology

Tags: process, operating-system, interrupt, scheduler

I'm doing some fill in the blanks from a sample exam for my class and I was hoping you could double check my terminology.

1. The various scheduling queues used by the operating system would consist of lists of **processes**.
2. **Interrupt handling** is the technique of periodically checking to see if a condition (such as completion of some requested I/O operation) has been met.
3. When the CPU is in **kernel mode**, a running program has access to a restricted set of CPU functionality.
4. The job of the **CPU scheduler** is to select a process on the ready queue and change its state.
5. The CPU normally supports a vector of **interrupts** so the OS can respond appropriately when some event of interest occurs in the hardware.
6. Using **traps**, a device controller can use idle time on the bus to read from or write to main memory.
7. During a **context switch**, the state of one process is copied from the CPU and saved, and the state of a different process is restored.
8. An operating system consists of a kernel and a collection of **application** programs that run as user processes and either provide OS services to the user or work in the background to keep the computer running smooth.

There are so many terms from our chapters, I am not quite sure if I am using the correct ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My thoughts:
1. **Processes** and/or **threads**. Jobs and tasks aren't unheard of either. There can be other things. E.g. in MS Windows there are also Deferred Procedure Calls (DPCs) that can be queued.
2. This must be **polling**.
4. Why **CPU** scheduler? Why not just scheduler?
6. I'm not sure about **traps** in the hardware/bus context.

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right about polling. I was unsure of what #6 was, but I believe CPU scheduler is correct for #4 since we have used that term specifically in our lectures. So many terms!